# Purpose of multiprocessors and multi-core processor

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, hardware, multicore

I do want to clarify things in my head and model concrete knowledge. dual-core with one processor system, only two threads within the one process can be executed concurrently by each core. Uni-core with two processor system, two different process can be executed by each CPU.
So can we say, each processor can execute processes concurrently. While multi-core processor execute threads within the process concurrently?

Comment: You mean parallel, not concurrently. In parallel, one process or thread per core

Comment: Processes and threads are similarly scheduled on processors and there are no physical mapping between processes and processors. One process with 2 thread can execute on 2 processors simultaneously as 2 process of 1 thread each.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a process and thread are and how they relate to the hardware itself.

A CPU core can only execute 1 machine level instruction per clock cycle (so essentially, just 1 assembly instruction). CPU's are typically measured by the number of clock cycles they go through in a second. So a 2.5 GHz core can execute 2.5 billion instructions per second.

The OS (the operating system, like Windows, Linux, macOS, Android, iOS, etc.) is responsible for launching programs and giving them access to the hardware resources. Each program can be considered a "process".

Each process can launch multiple threads.

To ensure that multiple processes can share the same hardware resources, the idea of pre-emptive computing came about over 40 years ago.

In a nut-shell, pre-emptive computing, or time-slicing, is a function of the OS. It basically gives a few milliseconds to each thread that is running, regardless of which process that thread is a part of, and keeps the "context" of each thread so that the state of each thread can be handled appropriately when it's time for that thread to run; that's also known as a context switch.

A dual, quad, or even 128 core CPU does not change that, nor will the amount of CPU's in the system (e.g. 4 CPU's each with 128 cores). Each core can only execute 1 instruction per clock cycle.

What changes is how many instructions can be run in true parallel. If my CPU has 16 cores, then that means it can execute 16 instructions per clock cycle, and thus run 16 separate threads of execution without any context switching being necessary (though it does still happen, but that's a different issue).

This doesn't cover hyper-threading, in which 1 core can execute 2 instructions per cycle, essentially doubling your CPU count, and doesn't cover the idea of cache-misses or other low-level ideas in which extra cycles could be spent on a thread, but it covers the general idea of CPU scheduling.

Comment: Hello, this is exactly what i was thinking about. I couldn't explain it because of lack of english grammar. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sounded OK until the 'time-slicing' paragraph.  IME, any such explanation that ignores the absolutely-vital I/O completion scheduling/dispatching, and places emphasis on the CPU sharing that happens when there are more ready threads than cores, is misleading, if not wrong.

Comment: @MartinJames .. I didn't ignore I/O, but given the OP is already confused regarding the basic difference, it would have added more complexity and most certainly is not wrong, but feel free to take _your own_ time and add _your own_ answer explaining that instead of making assertions, as I'm sure it'd be helpful to everyone.